# CoreData: annotation: Failed to load optimized model error on google map sdk iOS 11

Tags: google-maps, core-data, ios11

My code run on iOS 10.3 correctly. but on iOS 11 on simulator or my iPhone get this error:

```
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/Users/imohammadi/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/054E361B-16B2-43D6-9708-A59401DE29B8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/71EBDC7D-4708-4349-A54B-08E3F6E38D48/iAtlas.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/Storage.omo'
```

When app run for first time, google map run correctlly, but after close and run again, app wants to load tiles from caches and crash by error.
downgrade GoogleMaps 2.2 and upgrade to last version cocoapods not solved error.

All log is here:

```
["/Users/imohammadi/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/054E361B-16B2-43D6-9708-A59401DE29B8/data/Containers/Data/Application/71371217-5D6D-4BC1-97C4-4ED1FEBDF8EF/Documents"]
2017-10-22 15:39:11.908262+0330 iAtlas[19195:648732] [MC] Lazy loading NSBundle MobileCoreServices.framework
2017-10-22 15:39:11.909174+0330 iAtlas[19195:648732] [MC] Loaded MobileCoreServices.framework
2017-10-22 15:39:11.927694+0330 iAtlas[19195:648732] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/imohammadi/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/054E361B-16B2-43D6-9708-A59401DE29B8/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/Users/imohammadi/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/054E361B-16B2-43D6-9708-A59401DE29B8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F46E955A-F5B6-42A8-B435-3A488DB69C55/iAtlas.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/Storage.omo'
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/Users/imohammadi/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/054E361B-16B2-43D6-9708-A59401DE29B8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F46E955A-F5B6-42A8-B435-3A488DB69C55/iAtlas.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/Storage.omo'
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/Users/imohammadi/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/054E361B-16B2-43D6-9708-A59401DE29B8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F46E955A-F5B6-42A8-B435-3A488DB69C55/iAtlas.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/Storage.omo'
=================================================================
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication applicationState]
PID: 19195, TID: 649127, Thread name: com.google.Maps.LabelingBehavior, Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 21
Backtrace:
4   iAtlas                              0x000000010f3049a4 GMSIsApplicationInBackground + 53
5   iAtlas                              0x000000010f2f2bfa -[GMSForegroundDispatchQueue initWithName:targetQueue:] + 269
6   iAtlas                              0x000000010f3d2a6e _ZN7gmscore6vector4text8GlyphSetC2ERKNS_4base10reffed_ptrINS0_16TextureAtlasPoolEEEPU28objcproto17OS_dispatch_queue8NSObjectPK8__CTFontff + 344
7   iAtlas                              0x000000010f3d1ed8 _ZN7gmscore6vector4text10GlyphCache11GetGlyphSetEPK8__CTFontf + 214
8   iAtlas                              0x000000010f3cf98e _ZN7gmscore6vector4text6GLText14PrefetchGlyphsERKNS_4base10reffed_ptrINS1_10GlyphCacheEEERKNSt3__16vectorItNS9_9allocatorItEEEEPK8__CTFontf + 22
9   iAtlas                              0x000000010f3cfa91 _ZN7gmscore6vector4text6GLText14PrefetchGlyphsERKNS_4base10reffed_ptrINS1_10GlyphCacheEEEPK8__CTLinebf + 207
10  iAtlas                              0x000000010f32775f _ZN7gmscore6vector12GLPointLabel22PrefetchGlyphsForGroupEPNS0_12GLLabelGroupE + 181
11  iAtlas                              0x000000010f327687 _ZN7gmscore6vector12GLPointLabel14PrefetchGlyphsEv + 33
12  iAtlas                              0x000000010f3966aa _ZN7gmscore6vector16LabelingBehavior23CreatePendingOperationsERKNSt3__13setINS_4base10reffed_ptrINS0_7GLLabelEEENS2_4lessIS7_EENS2_9allocatorIS7_EEEESE_SE_NS0_13LabelDrawModeE + 1096
13  iAtlas                              0x000000010f39601d _ZN7gmscore6vector16LabelingBehavior14RunLabelingJobERKNS_4base10reffed_ptrINS1_11LabelingJobEEE + 357
14  iAtlas                              0x000000010f395eaa ___ZN7gmscore6vector16LabelingBehavior14CommitInternalEPNS_8renderer14EntityRendererE_block_invoke + 22
15  Foundation                          0x0000000113fad948 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 334
16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000114bac2b1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000114c4bd31 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 81
18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000114b90c19 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 185
19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000114b901ff __CFRunLoopRun + 1279
20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000114b8fa89 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
21  Foundation                          0x0000000113f67e5e -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 274
22  iAtlas                              0x000000010f3d1165 -[GMSx_GTMSimpleWorkerThread main] + 337
23  Foundation                          0x0000000113f758ac __NSThread__start__ + 1197
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001162f36c1 _pthread_body + 340
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001162f356d _pthread_body + 0
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001162f2c5d thread_start + 13
2017-10-22 15:39:13.649828+0330 iAtlas[19195:649127] [reports] Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication applicationState]
PID: 19195, TID: 649127, Thread name: com.google.Maps.LabelingBehavior, Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 21
Backtrace:
4   iAtlas                              0x000000010f3049a4 GMSIsApplicationInBackground + 53
5   iAtlas                              0x000000010f2f2bfa -[GMSForegroundDispatchQueue initWithName:targetQueue:] + 269
6   iAtlas                              0x000000010f3d2a6e _ZN7gmscore6vector4text8GlyphSetC2ERKNS_4base10reffed_ptrINS0_16TextureAtlasPoolEEEPU28objcproto17OS_dispatch_queue8NSObjectPK8__CTFontff + 344
7   iAtlas                              0x000000010f3d1ed8 _ZN7gmscore6vector4text10GlyphCache11GetGlyphSetEPK8__CTFontf + 214
8   iAtlas                              0x000000010f3cf98e _ZN7gmscore6vector4text6GLText14PrefetchGlyphsERKNS_4base10reffed_ptrINS1_10GlyphCacheEEERKNSt3__16vectorItNS9_9allocatorItEEEEPK8__CTFontf + 22
9   iAtlas                              0x000000010f3cfa91 _ZN7gmscore6vector4text6GLText14PrefetchGlyphsERKNS_4base10reffed_ptrINS1_10GlyphCacheEEEPK8__CTLinebf + 207
10  iAtlas                              0x000000010f32775f _ZN7gmscore6vector12GLPointLabel22PrefetchGlyphsForGroupEPNS0_12GLLabelGroupE + 181
11  iAtlas                              0x000000010f327687 _ZN7gmscore6vector12GLPointLabel14PrefetchGlyphsEv + 33
12  iAtlas                              0x000000010f3966aa _ZN7gmscore6vector16LabelingBehavior23CreatePendingOperationsERKNSt3__13setINS_4base10reffed_ptrINS0_7GLLabelEEENS2_4lessIS7_EENS2_9allocatorIS7_EEEESE_SE_NS0_13LabelDrawModeE + 1096
13  iAtlas                              0x000000010f39601d _ZN7gmscore6vector16LabelingBehavior14RunLabelingJobERKNS_4base10reffed_ptrINS1_11LabelingJobEEE + 357
14  iAtlas                              0x000000010f395eaa ___ZN7gmscore6vector16LabelingBehavior14CommitInternalEPNS_8renderer14EntityRendererE_block_invoke + 22
15  Foundation                          0x0000000113fad948 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 334
16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000114bac2b1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000114c4bd31 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 81
18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000114b90c19 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 185
19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000114b901ff __CFRunLoopRun + 1279
20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000114b8fa89 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
21  Foundation                          0x0000000113f67e5e -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 274
22  iAtlas                              0x000000010f3d1165 -[GMSx_GTMSimpleWorkerThread main] + 337
23  Foundation                          0x0000000113f758ac __NSThread__start__ + 1197
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001162f36c1 _pthread_body + 340
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001162f356d _pthread_body + 0
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001162f2c5d thread_start + 13
2017-10-22 15:39:15.284603+0330 iAtlas[19195:649136] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_context_get_peer_sct_list: line 1754 received sct extension length is less than sct data length
2017-10-22 15:39:15.562982+0330 iAtlas[19195:649136] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_context_get_peer_sct_list: line 1754 received sct extension length is less than sct data length
2017-10-22 15:39:16.191452+0330 iAtlas[19195:648732] Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 2.4.30121.0
2017-10-22 15:39:16.195285+0330 iAtlas[19195:649136] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2017-10-22 15:39:16.195452+0330 iAtlas[19195:649136] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
```

Comment: It happened to me on my tests, so I "solved" it by `importing GoogleMaps` in the UnitTest.swift file. It makes little sense except that the linker may go crazy with the weird google imports. I had trouble with all parts of the project file when trying to build with google sdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was reported in Google issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64504919

As I can see, the issue was marked as fixed today (October 24, 2017). The Google rep wrote

> We believe that this issue should be solved in the Maps iOS SDK v2.5 release. If this issue still occurs, please let us know.

It looks like you have to update your SDK to the latest version 2.5 in order to solve the problem.

**UPDATE**

It looks like the issue wasn't solved in version 2.5, the bug was reopened in Google issue tracker.

Comment: Sorry, it is not worked I am using latest version 2.5.0 But warning is still there

Comment: @arunjos007 You are right, the bug was reopened by Google, because people are still experiencing the issue even in version 2.5.

Comment: Are you using Maps iOS SDK 2.6 now? Bug in issue tracker wasn't marked as fixed yet, but I guess Google fixed it in version 2.6.